# Moving a UIImageView from one point to another by touching any part of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying to get one `UIImageView *rocket`,
From its original location that I have set in the storyboard. It even has constraints for its initial position.

I want the rocket to move down by 77 pixels, when the screen is touched or hold. Once it's released, it will go back to its original position.

All these actions, I would like to have an 0.5s of animation so as not to see it jumps.

I hope I have enough information here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to what you want: a user action and a UI animation.

It sounds like you want to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. It also sounds like you want to have the entire view inside your view controller responsive to the long press.

To make the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` do something like this:

1. Create a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and add it as a gesture to the view in your view controller.
2. Create a method that the long press gesture can call when something happens. I usually call this something like `viewControllerLongPressed:`.
3. Add the new method to the gesture recognizer as a target.
4. Create two new methods for `moveRocketDown` and `moveRocketUp`.
5. Inside `viewControllerLongPressed:`, check the state of the sender. If it's `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and then call `moveRocketDown`. Do the same for `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and `moveRocketUp`.

At this point, you have a gesture recognizer that responds to user touch anywhere in the view (unless there are other gesture recognizer a interfering with the view).

Now, you just need to animate the rocket.

If you know exactly where the rocket will start the animation every time and end the animation every time, then I'd recommend creating constants for those two points. Something like _rocketStartCenter and _rocketEndCenter.

To animate the rocket, this method should work (I'm not at a computer to check, so I apologize if this is off):

```
[UIView animateViewWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         _rocket.center = _rocketStartCenter;
                      }];
```

I'd recommend using something around 0.3-0.35 seconds for animations, most iOS animations are in that range.

Comment: Hi, sorry to say, but my level of programming is not high to understand some parts of your solution. However, the following is what i have done, from my own understanding. I just wanted to know what is the proper command to move the rocket from start position "pointA" to "pointB" upon the first touch, and once released, the rocket will be back to "pointA". the following is my code. im actually do not really understand what does code means. the outcome is basically from the frame.x and frame.y that i have set, the rocket move back to the location that i have set in the storyboard.

Comment: CGRect frame = rocket.frame;
    frame.origin.x  = 72;
    frame.origin.y  = 343;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    rocket.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: I used this tutorial to learn how to animate in iOS. Spend some time going through it and it should cover any animation problems: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Comment: If the problem is with the gesture recognizer, try this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/. Both of them go through a sample project from beginning to end with code samples which should be helpful to see how someone else does it.